# How can I tell at run-time which control is in front?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, z-order

I have a container control (a `Panel`) that has a number of `Forms` loaded into it. Based on user interaction, I `.BringToFront()` certain forms. However, in other parts of the program, I would like to figure out which form is currently in front. (In other words, determine which was the last form to have its `.BringToFront()` method called.)

What's the best way to go about determining which control is in front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GetChildIndex` method of the Controls collection to get the index of a particular child control.

```
this.Controls.GetChildIndex(myControl);
```

The highest value is on top.

Comment: Picky point: according to the docs, the control with child index 0 is at the top of the z-order, and higher values are closer to the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, itowlson. And thanks for the answer, Volte.